# jQuery parsing XML finding specific elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm making a "TV guide" which gets data from an xml file. Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "programmes.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(status, error);
    },
    success: function(xml) {

        var programmeOne = $(xml).find('programme').first();
        $(xml).find('[programme[id="ch1pg1"]').text();
        $('.p1').text(programmeOne.find('title').text());

    }

});
```

And here's the XML:

```
<channel id="bbc1" source="Sky" date="20/12/2014">
<programme id="ch1pg1">
  <desc>The latest news, sport, business and weather from the BBC's Breakfast team.</desc>
  <title>Breakfast</title>
  <start>0900</start>
  <end>1100</end>
</programme>
<programme id="ch1pg2">
  <desc>James Martin presents the weekly cooking show. [HD] [S]</desc>
  <title> Kitchen</title>
  <start>1100</start>
  <end>1200</end>
</programme>
<programme id="ch1pg3">
  <desc>descriptions [HD] [S]</desc>
  <title>second  Kitchen</title>
  <start>1200</start>
  <end>1300</end>
</programme>
```

When I remove

```
$(xml).find('[programme[id="ch1pg1"]').text();
```

The code works, but all programme 1's from each channel use the same title from ch1pg1.

How can I make the function only use the "title" element from the parent element "programme" which has an id of "ch1pg1"?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly when searching by `id` you can use the `#` selector to make things both quicker and shorter.

Your second line of code does not work because you are returning a string, and then attempting to use jQuery methods on it, which will not work. Instead return the jQuery object and use that. Try this:

```
success: function(xml) {
    var $programmeOne = $(xml).find('#ch1pg1');
    $('.p1').text($programmeOne.find('title').text());
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tr1utg50/)